# Create sf multiploygon from a subset of points in grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

Note, this question is [also posted here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297590/create-sf-multiploygon-from-a-subset-of-points-in-grouped-data), but SO my be a better venue...? I can remove the GIS posting if SO is an OK venue.

I have a reproducible dataset with relocations of two animals (data below). For each location there is a `DateTime` stamp and a general season `IndYearCorePeriod` (`Winter`, `Summer`, and  `None`).

```
> head(dat)
       IndYear Latitude Longitude            DateTime IndYearCorePeriod
1 BHS_001-2015 45.01785 -111.5670 2015-01-07 05:52:00            Winter
2 BHS_001-2015 45.01799 -111.5674 2015-01-07 06:48:00            Winter
3 BHS_001-2015 45.01795 -111.5673 2015-01-07 07:15:00            Winter
4 BHS_001-2015 45.01733 -111.5408 2015-01-07 17:02:00            Winter
5 BHS_001-2015 45.01452 -111.5329 2015-01-08 19:01:00            Winter
6 BHS_001-2015 44.98944 -111.5415 2015-03-21 07:02:00              None
```

For each `IndYear` I would like to make two separate polygons when `IndYearCorePeriod != "None"` (i.e. one for `Summer` and another for `Winter`). Polygons can represent minimum convex polygons (i.e. `mcp` or `chull`). Using the `dat` below I am able to make an `sf` points object, but have not been able to then make the polygons as described above. My thought would be to work within a loop but suspect there is a much better approach in `sf` and `dplyr`.

The desired solution from these data would be an `sf` multipolygon with a `Summer` and `Winter` polygon for each `IndYear. Once the polygons are created, my hope is to intersect the polygons with a larger point data set and summarize the`DateTime` values within each polygon.

My real data represents close to 1 million locations from 350 `IndYear`s.

```
datSF <- dat %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), agr = "identity") %>%
    st_set_crs( "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Thoughts on generating multiple polygons from `datSF` would be much appreciated.

```
dat <- structure(list(IndYear = c("BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", 
"BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", 
"BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", 
"BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", "BHS_001-2015", 
"BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", 
"BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", 
"BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", 
"BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012", "BHS_011-2012"), Latitude = c(45.0178464, 
45.0179942, 45.0179475, 45.0173283, 45.0145206, 44.9894375, 44.9900889, 
44.9874772, 44.9897919, 44.9890256, 44.9420158, 44.9397328, 44.9412822, 
44.8635131, 44.8289894, 45.120814, 45.120802, 45.120761, 45.116529, 
45.105876, 45.104906, 45.103481, 45.119494, 45.118741, 45.118455, 
45.011676, 45.014516, 45.010205, 45.007998, 45.008031), Longitude = c(-111.5669881, 
-111.5673925, -111.5672922, -111.5408156, -111.5328619, -111.5414744, 
-111.5409731, -111.5406083, -111.5476233, -111.5411953, -111.4645483, 
-111.4678228, -111.464585, -111.4622411, -111.4641572, -110.817359, 
-110.817405, -110.818067, -110.806221, -110.797895, -110.793635, 
-110.791884, -110.800843, -110.80594, -110.803976, -110.837199, 
-110.841477, -110.84738, -110.838413, -110.839451), DateTime = structure(c(1420635120, 
1420638480, 1420640100, 1420675320, 1420768860, 1426942920, 1427036520, 
1427083320, 1427410920, 1427457660, 1435741200, 1435788000, 1435834860, 
1435975200, 1436022000, 1329436800, 1329458400, 1329480000, 1329501600, 
1329523200, 1334660400, 1334682000, 1334703600, 1334725200, 1334746800, 
1341054000, 1341075600, 1341097200, 1341118800, 1341140400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), IndYearCorePeriod = c("Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at a polygon? Considering showing a long way using one *IndYear*?

Comment: I am asking for help to make the polygons and have not done so yet.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site for open-ended questions. You should do the research, make an attempt, and come back with any issues for us to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your thoughts. I thought the question was a bit open ended for SO, thus the initial post at GIS. That said, SO is way more efficient in generating an answer and I figured it would get migrated back to GIS if it was not appropriate here. The question is specific a reproducible. Hopefully it will be useful to others.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/297590/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'trick' is to use `group_by`, and then `summarise`. This will throw all points together in the groups you defined. You can then use `st_cast` to create whatever you want, or, like in this case, `st_convex_hull`.

```
library( sf )

datSF <- dat %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude") ) %>%
  st_set_crs( "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" ) %>%
  filter ( IndYearCorePeriod %in% c( "Summer", "Winter") ) %>%
  group_by( IndYear, IndYearCorePeriod ) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  st_convex_hull()

library(mapview)
mapview( datSF )
```

[image]